# Push Technology : Is there any open source implementation for windows

Tags: cometserver

I have read about the push technologies recently. Using it real-time data streaming is very easy. I also saw an implementation called ajax push engine, but it runs on linux or mac server. I wanted to use this technology in an asp.net site.

So is there any open source implementation of the push technology that is available for direct use on windows platform ?

Comment: Are u looking for an API for a open source server product. What your usage. There is a few open source push engines, but they are categorized, so some push docs etc, others push calender, task via IMAP, and so on. What do you plan to push.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Orbited**
[Orbited](http://www.orbited.org) is an HTTP daemon that is optimized for long-lasting comet connections. It is designed to be easily integrated with new and existing applications. Orbited allows you to write real-time web applications, such as a chat room or instant messaging client, without using any external plugins like Flash or Java.

It can be installed as a windows service. The license is MIT.

**MethodWorx**
[MethodWorx](http://www.methodworx.com/comet.aspx) was developed out of this [series of articles](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CometAsync.aspx) on Code Project. It has an Open Source license.

> This is a packaged version of a
>   library the we used in some projects
>   to enable COMET polling or
>   Long-Polling within some of our
>   ASP.NET applications.
>
> It uses an Asynchronous HTTP handler
>   to keep ASP.NET connections open to
>   wait for events to occur, enabling
>   real-time AJAX callbacks.

**Lightstreamer**
[LightStreamer Moderato](http://www.lightstreamer.com) is free but not open source

**WebSync**
[WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/) is a standards-compliant scalable Comet server for IIS using .NET. It's also available on demand as a hosted service. This is neither free nor Open Source, but does have a free trial.

**Other**
There are several more Open Source Comet projects:

- [aspcomet](http://code.google.com/p/aspcomet/) The aim of this project is to develop a COMET implementation which does not require a custom server, but can run in native IIS.
- [emerge toolkit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emergetk/). No project activity in quite some time.

Comment: If I use orbited or MethodWorx in my application, does my hosting server need to provide additional resources, like any additional server or windows service etc. ?

Comment: @Sayem orbitd is a windows service, MethodWorx is part of your ASP.NET website

Comment: looks like methodworx is down as I checked it today, any new updates on this list?

Comment: FYI, WebSync has a free version with concurrency limits, and has been updated to support WebSockets now as well.