# .NET Comet engine

Tags: .net, comet

is there a .net based comet engine? like Ajax Push Engine

that is free and open source?

Comment: You probably want to watch the bonus question on this topic. It is sure to get some more answers over the next week. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392010/push-technology-is-there-any-open-source-implementation-for-windows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Orbited**
[Orbited](http://www.orbited.org) is an HTTP daemon that is optimized for long-lasting comet connections. It is designed to be easily integrated with new and existing applications. Orbited allows you to write real-time web applications, such as a chat room or instant messaging client, without using any external plugins like Flash or Java.

It can be installed as a windows service. The license is MIT.

**MethodWorx**
[MethodWorx](http://www.methodworx.com/comet.aspx) was developed out of this [series of articles](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CometAsync.aspx) on Code Project. It has an Open Source license.

> This is a packaged version of a
>   library the we used in some projects
>   to enable COMET polling or
>   Long-Polling within some of our
>   ASP.NET applications.
>
> It uses an Asynchronous HTTP handler
>   to keep ASP.NET connections open to
>   wait for events to occur, enabling
>   real-time AJAX callbacks.

**Other**
There are several more Open Source Comet projects:

- [aspcomet](http://code.google.com/p/aspcomet/) The aim of this project is to develop a COMET implementation which does not require a custom server, but can run in native IIS.
- [emerge toolkit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emergetk/). No project activity in quite some time.

Answer (score 3):

There is.. [PokeIn](http://pokein.com) Comet Ajax Library for ASP.NET . Works under IIS(.NET), Apache and Ngix(Mono) .

Comment: Only problem with Pokein is it's not  open source.. and is expensive